# What does the backslash beside the x mean here? In Haskell programming

Tags: function, haskell

I am currently new to Haskell and am doing revision for the Partial Function Application in Haskell. May I know **what is the backslash next to the x** enclosed in brackets of the **map function** as shown below? Is it just like a general way of representing a list? Thanks a bunch.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
doubleList = map(\x -> 2*x)
```

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with lists. `\x -> 2*x` is a [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) or [anonymous function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function). It has the same<sup>†</sup> effect as if you separately declared

```
doubleNumber :: Int -> Int -- The type could be more general; I stick to Int to keep it simple
doubleNumber x = 2*x
```

and then used

```
doubleList :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleList = map doubleNumber
```

...which by the way can itelf be considered a shorthand notation for the lambda function

```
doubleList = \l -> map doubleNumber l
```

or, almost-but-not-quite<sup>†</sup>-equivalently

```
doubleList l = map doubleNumber l
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I say but-not-quite because they can in some situation behave slightly different for reasons that have to do with Haskell's laziness; don't worry too much about that right now. Cf. https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form</sub>